# Clean tmp files on Heroku automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

My rails app import CSV files, generate PDF document and send it in email,
Its create a lot of tmp files and i would know the best way to automatically clean the tmp files and last generated documents

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a task to do this:

```
## lib/tasks/clean_temp_files.rb
desc 'Clean temporary files'

task clean_temp_files: :environment do
  ## Do something at here
end
```

Then, install [Heroku Scheduler](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler) to execute this task daily:

`rake clean_temp_files`